# Ajax infinity scroll returning same results

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, loops

I have this function which detects when the user gets to the bottom of the page, which then sends an ajax request to the server...

```
$(window).scroll(function()
    {
      // if at bottom, add new content:
      if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
      {
        var data = { mode: "bottom" };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'server/script/infinity.php',
            data: data,

            success: function(data){
              $("#load").append(data);              
            }
        });
      }

    });
```

This then outputs the data from the request in the `<div id="load"></div>` box. **My problem is that the returned results are the same as the results already on the page. I need to get the NEXT 5 results in the database.**

This is my current SQL query:

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"); 
while($post = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ... }
```

I have tried...

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5, 5");
```

See `LIMIT 5,5`, **this solves the problem for the next 5 results however when the user keeps scrolling the same problem occurs,** I need a way to loop through this but increasing the limit each time. Any ideas?

Comment: Have the client keep track of and send with the ajax request the "page" number or number of posts to skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5(X), 5")
```

X value has to be parametric.

javascript:

```
var data = {page : 10};
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'server/script/infinity.php',
            data: data,

            success: function(data){
              $("#load").append(data);              
            }
});
```

php :

```
    $starting_limit = $_REQUEST['page'];
mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ". $starting_limit.", 5");
```

You have to track starting_limit of query